# NumPy unique() returns indices that are out-of-bounds

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, indexing, point-clouds

I am trying to remove points from a point cloud that are too close to each other. My input is an mx3 matrix where the columns represent xyz coordinates. Code is as follows:

```
def remove_duplicates(points, threshold):
    # Convert to numpy
    points = np.array(points)

    # Round to within the threshold
    rounded_points = points
    if threshold > 0.0:
        rounded_points = np.round(points/threshold)*threshold

    # Remove duplicate points
    point_tuples = [tuple(point) for point in rounded_points]
    unique_rounded_points, unique_indices = np.unique(point_tuples, return_index = True)

    points = points[unique_indices]

    return points
```

The issue I am running into is that unique_indices contains values larger than the length of points (2265 and 1000 for my test data). Am I doing something wrong, or is this a bug in NumPy?

Edit: I should note that for very small inputs (tried 27 points), unique() appears to work correctly.

Comment: You may be having an overlap problem.  How about simply grabbing the points list returned from **unique**: points = unique_rounded_points

Comment: I was previously doing this, but I would prefer to return the original unrounded points.

Comment: What does `np.array(point_tuples)[ind]` return?  Same error?  What's the shape of `points` and `unique_rounded_points`?

Comment: What's the purpose of `tuple(point)`?  Are you trying to make a structured array so that `unique` returns unique tuples, as opposed to unique single values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So `points` is a 2d array, `(m,3)` in shape, right?

`point_tuples` is a list of tuples, i.e. row of `rounded_points` is now a tuple of 3 floats.

`np.unique` is going to turn that into an array to do it's thing

`np.array(point_tuples)` is a `(m,3)` array (again 2d like `points`).  The tuple did nothing.

`unique` will act on the raveled form of this array, so `unique_indices` could have values between 0 and 3*m. Hence your error.

I see 2 problems - if you want `unique` to find unique 'rows', you need to make a structured array

```
np.array(point_tuples, 'f,f,f')
```

Also applying `unique` to floats is tricky.  It's next to impossible to find 2 floats that are equal.  Rounding reduces this problem but does not eliminate it.

So it probably is better to use round in such a way that `rounded_points` is an array of integers.  The values don't need to scaled back to match `points`.

I can add an example if needed, but first try these suggestions.  I'm making a lot of guesses about your data, and I'd like to get some feedback before going further.

Comment: Packing the points in structured array completely fixed the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Since that earlier program works, then I suggest that you have an overlap problem: NumPy is access **points** on the right side while altering it on the left.  Use a different variable name

```
orig_points = points[unique_indices]
return orig_points
```

or simply return it directly

```
return points[unique_indices]
```

Comment: Tried this and it didn't fix the issue :/ Good Idea though.